# quickblox react-native-sdk

Tags: react-native, quickblox, http-status-code-422

I was trying to create a dialog using quickblox react-native-sdk. In ANDROID it worked perfectly fine, but in IOS(simulator) it is showing
**Error: Request failed: client error (422)**

```
QB.chat
      .createDialog({
        type: QB.chat.DIALOG_TYPE.CHAT,
        occupantsIds: [127929951],
      })
      .then(function (dialog) {
        console.log(dialog);
        
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);  
      });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
type: QB.chat.DIALOG_TYPE.CHAT,
```

Worked in my case. May be QB expects 0 as type for private chat but QB.chat.DIALOG_TYPE.CHAT in enum is type 3 which is not working in our case.

Comment: This is Nikolay from QuickBlox support. This answer is correct. You may also update the SDK to the latest version:
[https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-react-native-sdk/releases/tag/0.5.14-beta](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-react-native-sdk/releases/tag/0.5.14-beta)